# new to coding started learning cpp wanted to ask what is wrong with my code

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int coin1, coin2, coin3;
    cout << "enter a number for coin 1 0= ";
    cin >> coin1;
    cout << "enter a number for coin 2 = ";
    cin >> coin2;
    cout << "enter a number for coin 3 = ";
    cin >> coin3;
    if (coin1 == 1) {
        if (coin2 == 1) {
            cout << "you won" << endl;
        }
    } else if (coin2 == 1) {
        if (coin3 == 1) {
            cout << "you won" << endl;
        }
    } else if (coin1 == 0) {
        if (coin2 == 0) {
            cout << "you won" << endl;
        }
    } else if (coin2 == 0) {
        if (coin3 == 0) {
            cout << "you won" << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "you lost" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting output fine till the second else if but code does not work(show any output) when `coin2=0` and `coin3=0`. the else one also dont work all those above that work fine. this was basically a college task.I tried adding another if for the 0 value ones it did fix some issues but still did not fix the issue of not showing 'you lost' in else statement. thought it was a compiler issue tried on different compilers online same issue.

Comment: `if (coin1 == 1) {` and `else if (coin1 == 0) {` If you are only entering 0 or 1, one of these 2 will always be true. Meaning `else if (coin2 == 0) {` and `}else {` will always be skipped.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: You may want to map out your "truth table" here as to what behaviours constitute a win, and which a loss. I'm not sure I understand your logic.

Comment: Hint: if `coin1 == 1` but `coin2` and `coin3` are `0`, there is no defined path in the `if` statements that allows for that scenario to print anything. As was said, you need to think about the "truth table" of every combination of input values.

Comment: First of all, when learning C++ be *extremely humble*. Never assume it "was a compiler issue", compilers do have bugs but you're unlikely to encounter one with such simple code. Typically you have to be doing something really intense with a new, less-explored C++ feature, or working on a more obscure ISA for that to ever occur.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step ⏯️ carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: *thought it was a compiler issue*  More likely it is a PEBKAC issue, and easily fixed with [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/4641116)

Comment: [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you want nested if statements like that. If `coin1` is 1 and `coin2` is 0, for example, the program will exit with no output.

Also, as pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77183173/new-to-coding-started-learning-cpp-wanted-to-ask-what-is-wrong-with-my-code/77183223#comment136066877_77183173), if you only ever enter 0 or 1, anything past the third if statement is unreachable.

Your logic can be simplified I think. It looks like the logic you were trying to implement is that the user wins if:

- `coin1` and `coin2` are both 1
- `coin1` and `coin2` are both 0
- `coin2` and `coin3` are both 1
- `coin2` and `coin3` are both 0

Assuming that you only ever enter 0 or 1, that means that you can simplify this to be "the user wins if `coin1 == coin2` or if `coin2 == coin3`. So, you only need a single `if` statement:

```
if (coin1 == coin2 || coin2 == coin3) {
    cout << "You win" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "You lose" << endl;
}
```